# How to extract date, weekday and date bounds from sentence android(java)?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to extract data from sentences like this:

> "every day before 27 march"
>
> "mon, wed, sun except 29,30 march, 1,2 april"
>
> "weekdays after 20 march"
>
> "weekends before 3 april"
>
> "1, 5 , 7 april"
>
> and other combinations ...

Is there any standard solution for this problem?
It's not an imaginative literature. It's just server response with well known answer structure. 
http://s13.postimg.org/6gjtuzyo7/image.jpg Not so many combinations, I think.

Comment: No.  Natural language processing is something people are currently spending 10s of millions on and getting PHDs to work on.

Comment: My recommendation is to just decide on a few specific formats that you want to support and write tailor-made parsing code to recognize the pieces in those chosen formats.

Answer (score 0):

as we are talking about NLP for date/time , you should definitely check out [prettytime](http://www.ocpsoft.org/prettytime/) nlp library written in java. it served us so well.